# Is there a way to perform a memdump of an android device?

Tags: ram

Is there a way to perform a memdump of an android device? I need the content of the entire memory (RAM). Maybe there is a shell command (meminfo will not do because it displays only memory information, not the content of RAM) or maybe somebody has a program which does this.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I want to see if there is a pattern in the free memory space

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Android uses Linux as kernel [`/dev/kmem`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/kmem) exists. It's a virtual character device file that is an image of the main memory of the computer.
You can simply dump it with

```
cat /dev/kmem > file
```

but only as root.

Comment: thanks, this is what I wanted, also there is a physical memory file (/dev/mem) I will look to see what is the difference, but now I know where to look at.

Comment: `cat` for any `mem` device never work. Because `cat` read device sequentially and zero page never mapped in memory. Zero page must be not mapped for get `SIGSEG` (Segmenataion fault) on resolve `null` pointer. Then `cat` failed read and output `file` will be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GameGuardian](http://gameguardian.net/download) for this. Need root.

Memory editor tab - menu - memory dump - select range and folder - press ok - wait for toast "Dump end".

Here some video examples how to do this:

- [How to dump memory of any running processes in Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/248-how-to-dump-memory-of-any-running-processes-in-android-gameguardian/)
- [How to dump odex file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/251-how-to-dump-odex-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)
- [How to dump deleted file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/252-how-to-dump-deleted-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)